# SQL Sub queries Confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

In my understanding sub-queries sometimes are used to retrieve data from a separate table and include into the table we are currently populating. However, I cannot make sense of this code:

```
INSERT INTO ESOP_ODS.dbo.ActiveMonitoringDeviceFact (
    MonitoringDeviceID,
    DateID,
    TimeID,
    TenantID,
    ReportingDate,
    NumActiveDevices
)
SELECT
    MonitoringDeviceDim.MonitoringDeviceID,
    **(SELECT DateID FROM ESOP_ODS.dbo.DateDim WHERE DateDim.DateKey = CAST(@ReportingDate AS DATE)),
    (SELECT TimeID FROM ESOP_ODS.dbo.TimeDim WHERE TimeDim.TimeKey = @ReportingTime)**,
    TenantDim.TenantID,
    @ReportingDate,
    1
```

What is the function of the lines in bold, and why do we use a sub-query?

Comment: Not sure, because there's clearly more to this code.

Comment: The question is basically: 'why and how sub-queries are used to populate new table from an existing one?'

Comment: @DavydFridman it's using subqueries to retrieve the IDs of your #ReportingDate and #ReportingTime. It needs to look for them on the DateDim and TimeDim tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are *scalar* subqueries.  A scalar subquery returns one column and at most one row.  They can be substituted for constants in a SQL query --  at least in the `select`, `where`, `from`, `having`, and `order by` clauses.

These queries are looking but the `dateid` and `timeid` for particular parameters that are passed into the query.  It is a way of converting "key" values to "id" values, based on the nomenclature used in the query.

Note that if the scalar subquery returns no row, then the value is `NULL`.

Comment: Does that mean if the ActiveMonitoringDeviceFact table will have multiple rows, DateID and TimeID will be the same in every row?

Comment: @DavydFridman . . . As the code is structured, yes.  The subqueries are not correlated to the outer query.  They are filtering on a parameter and the parameter does not change during query execution.

Comment: Sort of. DateID is logically equivalent to the date stored in `@ReportingDate`. Unless there is a unique constraint, you should expect to find multiple rows for a given value of DateID and for a given value of TimeID (and likely the combination of the two). But why ask - just go examine your actual data or try inserting some simple test cases using your logic. No better way to learn than by doing your own experiments.

Comment: @SMor . . . They are different dimension tables, so I don't think duplicates are likely in this case.